# How to move a span after an img?

Tags: html, css

I have some HTML which is automatically generated, and I would like to know how to move a span after the image.

Here is the HTML

```
 <span>closed</span> <img alt="Click to reset" src="xxx" class="">
```

So if you notice that the span comes first and then the img.

I need it so it renders, the opposite like so

```
 <img alt="Click to reset" src="xxx" class=""> <span>closed</span>
```

As I say I can't touch the HTML, its automatically generated but I think there is a CSS trick to get around this right ?

### Edit

I forgot to mention that these two elements are wrapped in a `<div>`.

So  i.e:

```
 <div><span>closed</span> <img alt="Click to reset" src="xxx" class=""></div>
```

Comment: You'll have to make the block elements and use float:left or float:right

Comment: You can try float left/right or the Boostrap grid system.  You could also use JavaScript.

Comment: Are the elements the only children of their parent element?

Comment: some surrounding html would be useful

Comment: The html page is quite complex, but there is a surrounding div. Its actually inside a large cell of a grid.

Comment: By any chance if you can select the parent element, you can change the order of children by giving `direction: rtl;` to the parent.

Comment: Another solution is to use `flexbox` and its [order property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) - [example](http://jsfiddle.net/xx0s4dbr/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can you the [**Adjacent sibling selectors**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) from the span point of view and change the image `display` and `float` rules.

```css
div span + img { 
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

/* clarfix the float */
div:after {
  content: ".";
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>closed</span>
  <img alt="Click to reset" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/food" class="" />   
</div>
```

Another option would be to use a `flex` layout and change the order of your elements like so:

```css
div {
    display: flex;
    align-content: flex-start;
}

span { 
    order: 1;
    align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>closed</span>
  <img alt="Click to reset" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/food" class="" />   
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. After some playing around, this gave me what I want. thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

if you're willing to use jQuery you could use this method

```
$(function(){
    $('span').insertAfter($('img'));
});
```

or with css you can use

```
span{
    float:right;
}
img{
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: float right and left, floats just within the div?.. See my update

Comment: and floating within the grid is not what you want?

Answer (score 0):

One more possible method :)

```
div { display: table; }
img{ display: table-header-group; }
span { display: table-footer-group; }
```

[example](https://jsfiddle.net/vvr1p1v1/)